# Requirements to Authenticate users from Android application with ADFS

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on, adfs

I have limited web development experience and have been tasked with authenticating users through a client's ADFS 4.0 server to allow their employees to use a single set of credentials for this application and internal services. I have the time and willingness to learn about this topic but I did not realise the depth of it and would appreciate being pointed in the right direction!

The application being developed is being paired with a web portal for admin purposes and a database to store content for the application. The application is Android only.

I have been looking at ADAL; is this the correct approach for authenticating for both the web service and the native app? What details will I require from the client and what will they require from me to enable claims based authentication?

Any help is massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official samples for ADFS 4.0 are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/ad-fs-development).

There is a SPA adal.js example which also includes calling a web API.

There is an Android example for Azure AD which uses ADAL for Android [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-android).

The configuration is very similar so you can take the guidelines from the ADFS example to see how to set up the Android example in ADFS.